# How can I select next element after $(this)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```js
$("td").on("click", function(){
  var result = $(this).closest('table').siblings('form').find('input[name="inputname"]').attr('value');
  alert(result);
});
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<form>
<input name = 'inputname' value = "10">
</form>
<form>
<input name = 'inputname' value = "12">
</form>
```

When you click on `click`, it alerts `10`. All fine, `10` is exactly what I need to get. But I don't know why I have a bad feeling about `.siblings('form')`, Because second `form` is also in the siblings-scope of that `table`. While I just need to select that `form` which is under `table`, just that one *(not second `form`)*.

Again, the output is correct, and all I want is an alternative for `.siblings(form)` in this case, Is there?

In other word how can I define this in jQuery?

```
$(this).closest('table')./* next form */.find('input[name="inputname"]').attr('value');
```

Comment: nextSibling ? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nextsibling.asp sorry for w3schools link. I hear it's frowned upon around SO.

Comment: you can use `.siblings('form:first')`

Comment: or `.siblings('form').first()`

Comment: `$(this).closest('table').next('form').find('input[name="inputname"]').val();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`siblings('form')` returns two matches for your HTML sample. It is only because you end the chain with a call to [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) that you only get one result. As stated in the docs:

> The `.attr()` method gets the attribute value for only the first element in the matched set.

Note that `siblings` also looks backwards for matches, so if you would have a form preceding your table, it would look for the input box there.

You could use `next('form').first()` instead of `siblings('form')` to be sure to only look forward, and only take the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Your bad feeling is right. One day your designer would like to wrap some elements into some other elements and suddenly the program will stop working
mainly cause `.siblings("form")` will most likely not be any more a `form` buth rather a `<div>` (which holds the `form`).

I'd go for custom `data-*` attribute:

```js
$("[data-click]").on("click", function() {
  var target = $(this).data("click");
  var result = $("[data-target='"+target+"']").find("[name=inputname]").val();
  alert(result);
});
```

```css
[data-click] { /* how cool is that ;) */
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-click="form_1">click</td>
    <tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<form data-target="form_1">
  <input name = 'inputname' value = "10">
</form>

<form data-target="form_2">
  <input name = 'inputname' value = "12">
</form>
```

Perhaps settign the `data-target` to the `input` element would be an even better idea!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```js
$("td").on("click", function(){
  var result = $(this).closest('table').next('form').siblings('form').find('input[name="inputname"]').attr('value');
  alert(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
    <tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<form>
<input name = 'inputname' value = "10">
</form>
<form>
<input name = 'inputname' value = "12">
</form>
```

Comment: With the huge difference that this gets `12`